# Corona SDK getting list of contacts in iOS

Tags: ios, coronasdk, contacts

I have implemented contact picking in my app.

But... I would like to get the whole list of contact and put it to my `widget.newTableView`?

Is it possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the Corona SDK user, but have some experience in iOS development. And have some info that should help.

There 2 ways to get to the contacts:

1)Use standard iOS api to get view with list of contacts.
Basically iOS have a standart way to call a view with list of contacts and ability to choose one contact, wich is seemed to be used in Corona SDK.
[Call standard view controller of contacts iOS native](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1)(Rob gave you the link to example code of this way)

2)The second way is to get data from api and build custom view controller with custom interactions. Api to get just straight contacts-data and manipulate it. [Accesing Contacts Data Programatically iOS native](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW1)

**So if you look in docs of [Corona SDK Contacts Pluggin](http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/plugin/CoronaProvider_native_popup_addressbook/) You will see that there is no such API(Methods to get just data).**

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

So the workaround for this could be done in couple steps.

1) Write native iOS code to get the data(You should use objective-c or swift).(iOS 8 grant ability to create frameworks) so basically you should write little native framework to get data. Build it and get STATIC Library

2) Wrap it to Corona SDK plugin,like said in these doc's
[Corona SDK Pluggin Doc's](http://docs.coronalabs.com/native/plugin/index.html)

3) Use it in project, add it like in this api
[Corona SDK How to add Native iOS frameworks](http://docs.coronalabs.com/native/ios/index.html)

Enjoy!

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I am interesting in 2 way. But I can not understand how to use this direct API?

Answer (score 1):

I am not gone through Corona or link like

https://github.com/coronalabs/plugins-sample-native-popup-addressbook

But as above link is getting one record at a time , i am assuming there would be a array or dictionary of list of records.

So what you need to do , you need to get that array or dictionary which contains list of contacts and show those contacts to your tableview.

I have done same thing in iOS in which , i get Addressbook array which contains ABAPeople objects and i show name of contact in Tableview.

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the sample app for iOS contacts:

https://github.com/coronalabs/plugins-sample-native-popup-addressbook

Comment: hi, Rob! Thank you for your answer. I have already tried to get contact from native iOS popup list. This method opens popup contact list and you can pick 1 contact. But a would like to get the whole list of contact and save it to the table. Is it possible?